# Recording sound and upload using web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, audio, web, angular5

I am bulding a learning portal for a client and the client has asked for a feature where the user can record and upload sound directly from the browser (or browser plugin) to a custom made forum on the portal. The client envision having a button like [start recording] on the site. I am probably ending up with recommending against this feature but I would like to hear if any of you have done something similar and what you used.

This specific application is built using dotnet core 2.0 and Angular 5 in the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WebRTC could be an option if you can run your site under an SSL cert.

You may want to take a look to this example [here](https://gist.github.com/WebPlatformDocs/b0053b13f0dc7d3b8e0c).
Here you have another [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos) using the device camera.

You can store the response on a Blob and send it to your server.

It is an initial aproach but I think it could help you take a decision.